# Why a stacktrace of an exception is printed at last?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Here is my simple test code:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Line 1");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Line 2");
        }
    }
}
```

After running I'll get this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at Scratch.main(scratch_4.java:5)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I thought that "finally" code must be executed at last, but it's not.
What is the reason?

Comment: I think that the finally just is defined to execute before the code in `catch`.  I'd have to look that up in the language spec though to be sure.

Comment: @markspace: No, it's definitely executed after the catch block.

Comment: I accept the correction!  I'll leave my comment up though since I think it illustrates a possible misunderstanding.

Comment: @markspace I was going to say that the keyword `finally` should make it clear that it's the last thing to happen; but then I spotted that [the Oracle tutorial says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) "The finally block always executes when the try block exits.", which is a pretty misleading statement. Like JonSkeet says: it's definitely executed after the catch, if a matching exception was thrown by the try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `printStackTrace` prints to `System.err`, whereas you're writing to `System.out`. So you're writing to two different streams, and in your particular case it looks like the buffering involved has switched the output order from the actual execution order.

If you either write to a single stream (e.g. using `System.err.println` *or* calling `e.printStackTrace(System.out)`) or change your `catch` block to just write to `System.out` like your other lines do, you'll see the order of try => catch => finally.